# Vanishing Ricci flow on a curved manifold

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, cosmology, differential-geometry

If I understand this right the Ricci flow on a compact manifold given by

$\partial g_{\mu \nu} = - 2R_{\mu \nu} + \frac{2}{n}\!R_{\alpha}^{\alpha} \,g_{\mu \nu}$

tends to expand negatively curved regions and to shrink positively curved regions.

Looking at the above definition I`m wondering if the parameter n can be used to achieve $\partial g_{\mu \nu} = 0 $ even if the Ricci tensor is not zero such that the validity of physics, that depends on the metric to be constant (as a precondition), could be extrapolated to curved manifolds to describe an expanding universe with a positive cosmological constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the impression that OP is referring to [Normalized Ricci Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_flow#Mathematical_definition) (NRF):

$$  \frac{1}{2} \partial_t g_{\mu\nu} ~=~ -R_{\mu\nu} + \frac{\langle R \rangle}{n} g_{\mu\nu}~.  $$

Here $\langle R \rangle$ is the *average scalar curvature* over the full space-time $M$. The average procedure is often weighted with an Einstein-Hilbert Boltzmann factor. It is just a number (as opposed to a space-time dependent scalar quantity).

Also  $n$ is the space-time dimension, which is fixed, and hence cannot be easily varied as OP suggests.

Comment: Can someone explain to me the dimensions of the equation because the metric g is dimensionless normally and R the curvature, having units of inverse length squared.

Comment: Apparently here $[g] = [R][t]$, $[g_{\mu\nu}] [x]^2= [g]$, $[R_{\mu\nu}] [x]^2=[R]=1$.